# TypeError: getTodosFromUserDevice is not a function Also TypeError: saveTodoToUserDevice is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I have created a todo list and it works fine, but I need to add async storage to store the todo list when the page refreshes, or closes etc. So, I added async storage, but when I added `React.useEffect` it shows `TypeError: getTodosFromUserDevice is not a function` and `TypeError: saveTodoToUserDevice is not a function`

I have added two functions:

1. `getTodosFromUserDevice`
2. `saveTodoToUserDevice`

React UseEffect Code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    getTodosFromUserDevice;
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
    saveTodoToUserDevice(todos);
}, [todos]);
```

My The Function I gave:

```
const saveTodoToUserDevice = async todos => {
  try {
    const stringifyTodos = JSON.stringify(todos);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('todos', stringifyTodos);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
};

const getTodosFromUserDevice = async () => {
  try {
    const todos = await AsyncStorage.getItem('todos');
    if (todos != null) {
      setTodos(JSON.parse(todos));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you try `getTodosFromUserDevice()`?

Comment: you mean where should i try it

Comment: In first `useEffect`

Comment: Notice to the `()` parentheses